# Serve audio from network location

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, html, extjs

I'm trying to serve a piece an audio file (from a web-application) that is stored on a network location, it works but I'd like to actually process the ajax that is made so that I can show a mask while the audio is being buffered/fetched.

The C# code looks like this:

```
        long fSize = (new System.IO.FileInfo(FilePath)).Length;
        long startbyte = 0;
        long endbyte = fSize - 1;
        int statusCode = 200;
        if ((request.Headers["Range"] != null))
        {
            //Get the actual byte range from the range header string, and set the starting byte.
            string[] range = request.Headers["Range"].Split(new char[] { '=', '-' });
            startbyte = Convert.ToInt64(range[1]);
            if (range.Length > 2 && range[2] != "") endbyte = Convert.ToInt64(range[2]);
            //If the start byte is not equal to zero, that means the user is requesting partial content.
            if (startbyte != 0 || endbyte != fSize - 1 || range.Length > 2 && range[2] == "")
            { statusCode = 206; }//Set the status code of the response to 206 (Partial Content) and add a content range header.                                    
        }
        long desSize = endbyte - startbyte + 1;
            //Headers
            response.StatusCode = statusCode;
            response.ContentType = String.Format(@"audio/{0}", fileLocation.Split('.')[1]);
            response.AddHeader("Content-Length", desSize.ToString());
            response.AddHeader("Content-Range", string.Format("bytes {0}-{1}/{2}", startbyte, endbyte, fSize));
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", Regex.Replace(fileLocation, @"([^\\]+$)", v => String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", v.Value)));
            //Data
            response.WriteFile(FilePath, startbyte, desSize);
            response.End();
```

The C# code is called directly from the src tag like so:

```
Ext.create('widget.panel', {
                           html: '<audio controls>' +
                            '<source src="/api/getaudio/' + encodeURIComponent(audioPath) + '/"' +
                            ' type="audio/' + el.getAttribute('data-audiolocation').split('.')[1] + '">' +
                            '</audio>',
                     });
```

But since the ajax-call isn't made from the framework I can't process the request.

I've tried to lift it out like so:

```
var audioFile = Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '/api/getaudio/' + encodeURIComponent(audioPath) + '/',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(response, opts) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            failure: function(response, opts){
                console.log(response);
            }
        });

html: '<audio controls src="' + audioPath + '"></audio>',
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

What can I do to do the ajax-call outside of the html-tag and then put/inject the response to the html5-audio-player-thing?

Or can I somehow intercept the ajax within the function itself and add a mask or do whatever there? I've seen some people talking about catching ALL ajax-requests but that seems overkill just to get this to work.

Comment: Look at the events available for the <audio> element - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events You should be able to attach a listener to the element to handle the `loadstart` and `loadeddata` events for example, and hook into it that way.

Comment: Cheers, I'll give it a try :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stuart pointed me in the right direction.

However I was using the frameworks "Ext.get" method to access the HTML5 audio player which had other methods (with the same names) so I had to use normal javascript and add a listener for the "canplay" event:

```
 document.getElementById('audioPlayer').addEventListener("canplay", function(event) {
                        Ext.get('audioWindow').unmask();
                        document.getElementById('audioPlayer').play();
                    }, true);
                    document.getElementById('audioSource').src = '/api/getaudio/' + encodeURIComponent(audioPath) + '/';
                    document.getElementById('audioPlayer').load();
```